# Wordpress plugins for making gallery

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery

I wish to make a gallery similar to http://welovewp.com

Can anyone guess, how this is made ?

Is there any already existing plugin or do we need to code for that ourselves.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some gallery plugins for WP:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-gallery-plugin/screenshots/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

For an extensive list of gallery plugins, try the WordPress.org plugins site:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

BTW, the site you're linking to doesn't seem to be using a gallery plugin.
They're using a list of posts with a featured image and URL styled in HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 1):

[Indranil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164477/indranil) has given you options for generating galleries out of photos stored on your server. If your photos are stored on some photo sharing website, you'll have search for those kind of specific plugins.

For example, if your photos are stored on Flickr, you can try any of these 3 plugins -

- [Awesome Flickr Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin/)
- [Slickr-Flickr](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slickr-flickr/)
- [Flickr Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flickr-gallery/)